# Methods of decreasing algorythm complexity

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am trying to programme a function that takes a non-negative integer, and returns a list of non-negative integer pairs whose values - when squared - sum to the given integer.

examples:

```
  5  -->  [ [1, 2] ]
 25  -->  [ [0, 5], [3, 4] ]
325  -->  [ [1, 18], [6, 17], [10, 15] ]
```

My solution works in an IDE but when I submit it to codewars I receive exit code error 139: FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. The codewars documentation indicates that this is due to an inefficient algorythm.

Initially my solution contained a nested loop which was causing long run time but I have since refactored my code to remove this. Despite this reduced complexity I still get the same error.

Any suggestions how I can further decrease the complexity?

```
const allSquaredPairs = (n) => {
//get array of all numbers between 0 and sqrt of n
let possibleNums = Array(n)
.fill()
.map((_, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) ** 2 <= n) return i + 1; //only numbers lesser than sqrt of n
})
.filter(n => n!=undefined)
possibleNums = [0, ...possibleNums];

const matchingPairs = [];
while (possibleNums.length){

    const num1 = possibleNums[0];
    const num2 = possibleNums[possibleNums.length-1];
    const sum = num1 ** 2 + num2 ** 2

    if (sum === n) matchingPairs.push([num1, num2]);
  
    if (sum > n ) possibleNums.pop()
    else possibleNums.shift()


  }
return matchingPairs;
};
console.log(allSquaredPairs(25));
```

Comment: `Array(n).map().filter()` make three copies of your already large array.  That is not efficient from a memory usage point of view.  While the first two copies of the array will be eligible for garbage collection, they will all three exist at the same time, thus increasing your peak usage.  Please as other answers have already said, pre-created all possible values in an array is just not an efficient approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution allocates an array of length n, and then iterates over it. That means that the memory requirement for your solution increases linearly as n increases.

You could implement this without allocating that array so that the memory requirement is constant no matter how large the value of n.

```js
const examples = [
  { input:   5, output: [ [1, 2] ] },
  { input:  25, output: [ [0, 5], [3, 4] ] },
  { input: 325, output: [ [1, 18], [6, 17], [10, 15] ] },
  { input: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, output: [] }
];

function allSquaredPairs(n) {
  const matchingPairs = [];
  const smallestIntegerLargerThanSquareRootOfN = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
  let lowerBound = 0;
  let upperBound = smallestIntegerLargerThanSquareRootOfN;
  while (lowerBound < upperBound) {
    const sum = lowerBound ** 2 + upperBound ** 2;

    if (sum === n) {
      matchingPairs.push([lowerBound, upperBound]);
      lowerBound += 1;
    } else if (sum < n) lowerBound += 1;
    else if (sum > n) upperBound -= 1;
    else console.log("ERROR!")
  }
  return matchingPairs;
}

examples.forEach(({ input, output}) => console.log({ n: input, expected: JSON.stringify(output), "  actual": JSON.stringify(allSquaredPairs(input)) }));
```

As a point of interest, I tried this with `let whatever = new Array(n)` at the start of the function, and for the max safe integer test case it threw `RangeError: invalid array length`. That's a different error than you were seeing, but it does illustrate how allocating an array of length `n` can complicate things.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. This is really clearly explained and I know how to avoid this mistake in the future.

Comment: Great! How do you get that button "Run Code snippet" ?

Comment: @SamGinrich https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/